# How can i solve Core policy blocking my request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying in my web page to make a request to the API when i click a button.I am trying to call the PhotosController but i am getting this error in the console

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/api/photos/1/photos' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I tried to allow access in the program with allowanyorigin
app.UseCors( x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

Comment: It depends on line where you use your CORS settings. Try to move it somewhere up before other ASP.NET middleware usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that, the CORS policy on your API server is blocking requests from your web page because the API server is returning a wildcard (*) value for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.

you need to configure the API server to allow requests from your web page's origin.

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
});
```

Now, this will allow request from `"https://localhost:4200"`.

> Note: `AllowAnyOrigin()` should be used only in the development not in
> the production. In production you should specify the origins that are
> allowed to access your web server.